# C++, CMake + MinGW - don't support non-latin symbols

Tags: c++, cmake, encoding, mingw

Greeting everyone,

When I try build project using CMake + mingw, I get second error:  "No rule to make target" and path with misunderstanding chars, but if I build project with only latin it is well.

Who knows how to fix it ?

I used second commands:

`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..`

`cmake --build . --config debug`

Also, CMake + VS compiler work fine.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Most likely it is constraint of `make` utility, which is used for build the project configured for MinGW. Just avoid paths containing special characters.